# Visual Studio extending namespace to produce error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, namespaces

I've encountered a problem in Visual Studio 2008 where recompiling a library project has Visual Studio to be unable to resolve the namespace.  The problem is that Visual Studio is extending the namespace unnecessarily.  For example, I have a cast like

```
... = (MyCompany.Dashboard.Data.BaseObjects.ZonesStruct) value;
```

which has compiled fine in the past suddenly begins to fail when recompiling.  Visual Studio is unable to resolve it and gives an error message "The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'MyCompany.MyCompany.Dashboard'...".  The change that kicked this off was adding a new class to the library.  The classes that are failing are existing and untouched classes.

I've encountered something similar once before, but that was the UI designer producing code that was explicitly qualified as "MyCompany.MyCompany...".  I'm hoping the root cause is the same in both situations.

Not sure if it's useful or not, but the default namespace of the library project is "MyCompany".  I've tried modifying that, but I didn't notice any changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this

`global::MyCompany.Dashboard.Data.BaseObjects.ZonesStruct`

The global:: escapes the namespace all the way out to the root namespace.  This isn't a Visual Studio issue, it's a conflicting namespace issue.

Comment: The workaround is effective, but any explanation on why the first qualifier gets duplicated?  This just came out of nowhere and now it would seem like I'm randomly adding global:: qualifiers when Visual Studio complains without a good understanding why.  I don't see how the conflict arose since this did work before.

Comment: The error you get only occurs(not 100% sure though) if either a namespace called MyCompany.MyCompany or a type MyCompany.MyCompany exists, which introduces ambiguity and therefore the error. When you specify global:: you tell the compiler that the first qualifier after that must be a nonnested namespace and the compiler resolves the ambiguity with that information. I'd recommend checking for erroneous names of namespaces or (less likely) types, to avoid needing to specify global:: over and over again.

Comment: Yes, somehow my class got generated with a "MyCompany.MyCompany" namespace.  Correcting that fixed the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't address the problem, just the symptom. But you could try ensuring that the namespace you have is in the global scope to start with by using

```
... = (global::MyCompany.Dashboard.Data.BaseObjects.ZoneStruct) value;
```

See MSDN for more information on the `global` keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx